# jQuery selector to denote "sameness"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<h2>Choose an option:</h2>
<a id="option-a" href="javascript:;" "class="shortcode-question ">Option A</a>
<a id="option-b" href="javascript:; " "class="shortcode-question">Option B</a>
<a id="option-c" href="javascript:;" "class="shortcode-question ">Option C</a>
<div id="content-a" class="shortcode-content">Content A</div>
<div id="content-b" class="shortcode-content">Content B</div>
<div id="content-c" class="shortcode-content">Content C</div>
```

I'm hiding the content and displaying the if the options are clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#question-a').click(function() {
    $('#content-a').show()
  })
})
```

I think you can see the problem here. I have to directly type and repeat the ID each time. Is there any selector like: `option-[sameness]` or `content-[sameness]`?

Comment: `$('[id^=content-]')`, you can use attribute selector, https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class selector like

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $contents = $('.shortcode-content');
  $('.shortcode-question').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $('#' + this.id.replace('option', 'content')).show();
    $contents.not($target).hide();
  })
})
```

```css
.shortcode-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Choose an option:</h2>
<a id="option-a" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question">Option A</a>
<a id="option-b" href="javascript:; " class="shortcode-question">Option B</a>
<a id="option-c" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question ">Option C</a>
<div id="content-a" class="shortcode-content">Content A</div>
<div id="content-b" class="shortcode-content">Content B</div>
<div id="content-c" class="shortcode-content">Content C</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [startWith selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('[id^="option-"]').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var cid='#content-'+this.id.replace('option-','');
      $(cid).show();
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('[id^="option-"]').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var cid='#content-'+this.id.replace('option-','');
      $(cid).show();
  })
})
```

```css
.shortcode-content{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="option-a" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question ">Option A</a>
<a id="option-b" href="javascript:; " class="shortcode-question">Option B</a>
<a id="option-c" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question ">Option C</a>
<div id="content-a" class="shortcode-content">Content A</div>
<div id="content-b" class="shortcode-content">Content B</div>
<div id="content-c" class="shortcode-content">Content C</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as:

```js
var options = $('a[id^=option]'), content = $('div[id^=content]');
content.hide();
options.each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(){
        content.hide();
        content.eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Choose an option:</h2>
<a id="option-a" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question">Option A</a>
<a id="option-b" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question">Option B</a>
<a id="option-c" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question">Option C</a>
<div id="content-a" class="shortcode-content">Content A</div>
<div id="content-b" class="shortcode-content">Content B</div>
<div id="content-c" class="shortcode-content">Content C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to target the class, and use some data attributes:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.shortcode-question').click(function() {
    // use this if you wanna hide others when one is picked:
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.shortcode-content').each(function (item) {
      $(this).toggle($(this).is('#content-' + id));
    });
    // or use this if you don't:
    // $('#content-' + $(this).data('id')).show();
  })
})
```

```css
.shortcode-content { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Choose an option:</h2>
<a id="option-a" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question" data-id="a">Option A</a>
<a id="option-b" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question" data-id="b">Option B</a>
<a id="option-c" href="javascript:;" class="shortcode-question" data-id="b">Option C</a>
<div id="content-a" class="shortcode-content">Content A</div>
<div id="content-b" class="shortcode-content">Content B</div>
<div id="content-c" class="shortcode-content">Content C</div>
```